# css only checkbox (with content attribute)

Tags: html, css, checkbox

how can I make a custom checkbox with css only (no JS no JQ) with content:"on" when checked and content:"off" when uncheked.

Thanks.

reedit

OK, after LOT of copy/paste/delete, [it work now](http://www.jsbin.com/iqobiy/3/).

Thank.

Comment: What about HTML, can you use HTML?

Comment: You mean like giving it a style and changing the background property? Or am i missing something

Comment: CSS affects style, attributes are not style, even though CSS can work off of attributes (on modern browsers) so I doubt you can do it without JS.

Comment: @Musa of course, I know HTML, lol, I appologize for not giving clear details.

Comment: @user1141356 yeah exactly, something like that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    position: relative;
    visibility: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox]:after {
    display: block;
    content: "OFF";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -30px;
    visibility: visible;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #d00;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
    content: "ON";
    background: #0a0;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: I like this very much, nice one :)

Comment: E X A C T E L Y, what I was looking for, though like the one I linked above, it isn't compatible with Firefox (am using Firefox 14)

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much

Comment: Looks great! Any suggestions to make it work on Edge?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Check out these blog posts by Ryan Seddon. He explain how you can play with checkbox and CSS

http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css

http://www.thecssninja.com/css/futurebox3

http://www.thecssninja.com/css/css-tree-menu

Answer (score 0):

Creating an actual element with CSS isn't possible. You can however style a checkbox using css.

An example:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    outline: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

Relying on pure CSS is also a give-or-take when dealing with different browsers and platforms. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is impossible with just css. Css decorates a html element and does not change its properties. If you click the checkbox, the box will have to do a postback to show it on the page. In which case the css will be the same. You need javascript.

What makes you not want to use javascript?

Comment: lol, Well, to be sincere, am afraid of JS though am learning it right actually.... and if ever you van add some JS stuff to make what Zoltan Toth posted above works on Firefox at least, I'll take it for sure :)