# Style label to customize checkbox appearance?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, label

How can I make [this](http://www.jsfiddle.net/a8Tk3/1/) custom checkbox (from my [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465507/css-only-checkbox-with-content-attribute) post) works on Firefox?
it seems its possible by using a personalized label and hide the checkbox but I dont know how to do that.

Please, if you need more details for you to help me, just let me know.

edit

It's [done now](http://www.jsbin.com/iqobiy/3/).

Comment: Hate to burst your bubble, but that doesn't work in Opera, either. The `before` and `after` pseudo classes generally don't work with input elements.

Comment: @cimmanon well I dont know why it's not working for you using Opera, but it's working for me.

Comment: If you solved your own problem, please either post the answer and accept it, or delete the question.