# How do I make an HTML checkbox look like a paper form checkbox?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have several html checkboxes I'd like to style like a paper form:

[image: Paper form checkboxes]

1. Is there any way to do this with CSS?
2. Is there any way to build a control that looks like this but *acts* like a checkbox?

When the box is checked, there should be an X in it:

[image]

---

**Update**

For those of you looking for a similar question: [Make checkbox in chrome look like one in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627961/make-checkbox-in-chrome-look-like-one-in-ie)

This one has some pretty good answers also.

Comment: I would suggest you to ask questions that are not suggestions based, and have some bugs or needed to get solution. This is opinion based.

Comment: possible duplicate of [css only checkbox (with content attribute)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465507/css-only-checkbox-with-content-attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution based on your mockups:

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* Hide default checkbox */
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

/* Style custom checkbox (indicated by <span>) that corresponds to its hidden version */
input[type=checkbox] + label span {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 0 4px 0 8px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 'Checked' state */
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label span::after {
    content: "X";
}
```

```html
<form>
  Occupant
        
  <input type="checkbox" id="owner" name="occ" value="Owner"/>
  <label for="owner"><span></span>Owner</label>
        
  <input type="checkbox" id="tenant" name="occ" value="Tenant"/>
  <label for="tenant"><span></span>Tenant</label>
        
  <input type="checkbox" id="vacant" name="occ" value="Vacant"/>
  <label for="vacant"><span></span>Vacant</label>
</form>
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this but you need to create your checkbox images, to use it.

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    position: relative;
    visibility: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox]:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -30px;
    visibility: visible;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background:url(http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/yTo/gj4/yTogj4zEc.png);
    background-size:100%;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
    content: "";
    background: url(http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/ncX/jL6/ncXjL6rcB.png);
    background-size:100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bprhe4L/1/)

**Mozilla FireFox UPDATE**

Using just some dummy elements, for here using label and using it by applying CSS to it.

```css
label.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {display:none;}
label.checkbox span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:25px; /* This must be depend on image resolution */
    height:25px; /* This must be depend on image resolution */
    background:url(http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/yTo/gj4/yTogj4zEc.png);
    background-size:100%;
    -moz-background-size:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:3px;
}
label.checkbox :checked + span {
    background:url(http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/ncX/jL6/ncXjL6rcB.png);
    background-size:100%;
    -moz-background-size:100%;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"/><span></span> Whatever you wanna say here... </label>
```

> **Note :** But still will not work in [old browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3achecked#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Thanks, still i don't know why someone down voted, never mind. :)

Comment: I like down vote too but with comments, why? So that i could improve myself. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: OK, i updating Answer for Mozilla Firefox, it need some dummy elements, but would work great.

Comment: @ChrisWeber Check the update for Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

< span onclick="this.innerHTML = (this.innerHTML ? '' : 'X')">

**CSS**

```
span{
display:inline-block;
width:15px; 
height:15px; 
font:14px verdana; 
border:solid 1px black;
color:green;
vertical-align:baseline;
cursor:pointer;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ApHME/59/

Comment: font should be `verdana`

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to hide the real `input[type=checkbox]` and use an `:after` pseudo-element to create anything you want in front of the checkbox. Here's a question with a similar problem: [css only checkbox (with content attribute)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465507/css-only-checkbox-with-content-attribute). Then just use CSS the way you want to stylize it.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question that I linked already have the answer!